# Не получается получить session_id в NGINX

Tags: nginx, сессия, модули, config

Который день не могу получить session_id в ngx_http_ssl_module и openssl. Сначала оказалось, что прямое обращение к переменным вроде ssl_session_s::session_id устарело, начиная с версии 1.1 (https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/OpenSSL_1.1.0_Changes). Затем, как оказалось, SSL_client_hello_get0_session_id не возвращает значение. Обращение к встроенным переменным тоже не получилось (мой вопрос) [Не получается получить встроенные переменные в коде динамического модуля NGINX](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1195624/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8f-nginx)
И еще один способ (функции SSL_SESSION_get_id, SSL_session_reused, SSL_SESSION_get0_id_context, SSL_set_session_id_context) тоже не получился, поскольку session_id, сохраненный с ним контекст и флаг isReused в итоге меняются как попало, не связанно друг с другом, и не держатся дольше 5 обновлений, хотя keep_alive_timeout (предоставил ngx_http_core_module) и ssl_session_timeout (предоставил ngx_http_ssl_module) установлены в 1h.

```
static int readSessionData (struct SessionData *sessionData,ngx_http_request_t *r) {
    //sessionData - структура, в которую я записываю все данные
    ngx_ssl_connection_t *ssl_conn = r->connection->ssl; 
    SSL_SESSION * session=SSL_get_session(ssl_conn->connection);
    sessionData->version=(char *)SSL_get_version(ssl_conn->connection); //версия работает   
    unsigned int idLen=0;
    const unsigned char * p=SSL_SESSION_get_id(session,&idLen);
    sessionData->idLen=idLen;
    getSessionIdView(sessionData->idView,p); 
//getSessionIdView функция переводит символы char в числа, то есть число 255 записывает в три позиции   
    sessionData->oldSession=SSL_session_reused(ssl_conn->connection);   
    sessionData->ctx=SSL_SESSION_get0_id_context(session,&sessionData->ctxLen);  
}
  

  
static int saveIdContext(char * name,ngx_http_request_t *r) {
    //сохранение контекста name при определенной команде
    ngx_ssl_connection_t *ssl_conn = r->connection->ssl; 
    SSL_SESSION * session=SSL_get_session(ssl_conn->connection);
    SSL_SESSION_set1_id_context(session,(unsigned char *) name,strlen(name)+1);
    //SSL_set_session_id_context(ssl_conn->connection,(unsigned char *) name,strlen(name)+1);
//функция SSL_set_session_id_context не имеет антипода, то есть гета, поэтому сохраненное значение теряется 
//https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/SSL_CTX_set_session_id_context.html

        return 0;
    }
```

Файл конфигурации

```
http {

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
     ...
     
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;  
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    server {
      listen 443 ssl;
      
      server_name 10.71.5.201;
          
    keepalive_timeout 1h;
    keepalive_requests 1000;
    #lingering_time 5m;
    #lingering_timeout 5m; #ни один тайм аут не помог
    
    #client_body_timeout 1h;
    #client_header_timeout 1h;
    ssl_session_timeout 1h;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/SSL/cert.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/SSL/cert.key;
    #ssl_handshake_timeout 10m;
        
    ssl_session_tickets on;
          
        ...

    }
    
}
```

Посоветуйте что-то, пожалуста.